# PyQt application closes successfully, but process is not killed?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, sys

i just noticed that when i run a pyqt application and close it, the application closes , but the process is still alive. Apparently the process that was running does not close even after closing the application.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Projects\XYZ\XYZ\XYZ.py", line 414, in <module>
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
SystemExit: 0
```

When i searched online , its says that if the return value is 0 , it is a normal termination. As you see the process keep on pilling up as i run the application.

[image]

So how do i overcome this problem?

Comment: You should put the solution in a separate answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a problem specific to IDLE.

There are several issues on the python bug tracker that are closely related (e.g. [8093](http://bugs.python.org/issue8093) and [12540](http://bugs.python.org/issue12540)), but they are now closed and resolved as "fixed".

Since it appears that you are using a very old version of python (2.5), you should be able to solve the problem by upgrading.

Comment: The reason i'm using python 2.5 is that i'm using scapy for packet capture , and it dosen't support python 2.7 for some reason. Otherwise i would love to use python 2.7 .

Comment: @thecreator232. Well, those fixes aren't going to be backported to python-2.5, so you'll have to fix it yourself if you want to resolve the issue. The 12540 issue has [patches](http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/cc86f4ca5020) for python3, so that should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 7):

**SOLUTION**

This a quick fix  , that i was able to make to solve this problem.

```
import psutil, os

def kill_proc_tree(pid, including_parent=True):    
    parent = psutil.Process(pid)
    for child in parent.children(recursive=True):
        child.kill()
    if including_parent:
        parent.kill()


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow() # <-- Instantiate QMainWindow object.
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
app.exec_()


me = os.getpid()
kill_proc_tree(me)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following?

```
sys.exit(app.exec_)
```

It's common practice among PyQt developers, and an easy way to cleanly quit your program. You should, however, upgrade to Python 2.7 or Python 3.3.